# Databinding in Behavior inside a style

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, behavior

I created a customcontrol (Autocomplete Lookup) which shows the search results based on the keywords I type in a textbox in a underlying popup.

I have the possibility to define the templates for the lookup part, that's the textbox representing the selected item and the suggestion part, the poput that shows the temporary results.

[image]

The Picture shows how the suggestion template looks like.

In xaml you can define the templates like this

```
<controls:AutoCompleteLookup
    Watermark="Tank"
    Provider={Binding TankProvider}
    SelectedItem={Binding SelectedCustomer}>
    <controls:AutoCompleteLookup.LookupTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type providers:TankLookupResult}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TankName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:AutoCompleteLookup.LookupTemplate>
    <controls:AutoCompleteLookup.SuggestionsView>
       <GridView x:Key="ContractStorageDetailGridView" x:Shared="False">
          <GridViewColumn Header="Tank" Width="Auto" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding TankName}" Foreground="Red"/>
              </DataTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Int. Reference" Width="Auto" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding InternalReference}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Customer" Width="Auto" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
       </GridView>
    </controls:AutoCompleteLookup.SuggestionTemplate>
</controls:AutoCompleteLookup>
```

This works just fine. Now I wanted to show Dynamic columns in the grid view. For this purpose I made a behavior that gets the dynamic data and displays the columns as needed (following codes is placed within the  from above)

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<mubctrls:DynamicColumnsBehavior GroupColumnsByKey="False">
    <mubctrls:DynamicColumnsBehavior.DynamicColumns>
        <mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn 
        Width="Auto"
        DetailSelector="{Binding Path=Data.SuggestionsViewDynamicColumnSelector, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}">

            <mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- The DataContext for the header is represented by the TDynamicColumnKey type. In this case it is UOMLookupResult. -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UOMName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>

            <mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- The DataContext for the cells is an instance that has a Root and a Detail property.
                        The Root property refers to the TankSuggestion while the Detail property refers to an instance of TDynamicColumnCellData
                        which in this case is TankUOMQuantity.
                -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Detail.DisplayQuantity}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

        </mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn>
    </mubctrls:DynamicColumnsBehavior.DynamicColumns>
</mubctrls:DynamicColumnsBehavior>
```

I struggled at first because a behavior didn't seem to be part of the visual tree and therefore it was difficult to get a DataContext. For this issue I found [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/). 
With the help of the mentioned BindingProxy I could pass the datacontext and bind to the dynamic data. So far so good. Unfortunately there's a lot of code required in xaml each time I want to use this control and the templates are most of the time identical so I tried to make a Style for the control. Most of the Items work, except the dynamic column part. I put the "Proxy" inside the  section but it seems, that this is not working because no dynamic columns are shown (I guess Data.SuggestionsViewDynamicColumnSelector is not found because of a missing DataContext). Does anyone know how to put the code above in a Style, to make it work correctly? Here's my attempt:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomsDetailWithDynamicColumnsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type mubctrls:AutoCompleteLookup}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AutoCompleteLookupBaseStyle}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <mubctrls:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mubctrls:AutoCompleteLookup}}}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Watermark" Value="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.CustomsDetail}"/>
    <Setter Property="NoSuggestionsErrorText" 
            Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FormatStringConverter}, 
                            ConverterParameter={x:Static resources:LabelResources.CustomsDetail}}"/>
    <Setter Property="LookupTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type customsDetail:CustomsDetailLookupResult}">
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} ({1})">
                            <Binding Path="DocumentNumber"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="SuggestionsView">
        <Setter.Value>
            <GridView x:Name="Test">
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.Id}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding Id}" Foreground="Red" Width="30"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.CustomsLicensePermit}" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding PermitName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.Customer}" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.ProductClassification}" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding ProductClassificationName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.Tank}" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding TankName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.Origin}" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding CountryOfOrigin}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.Date}" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding DocumentDate, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.DocumentNumber}" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mubctrls:SuggestionTextBlock Suggestion="{Binding DocumentNumber}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <!-- Definition of the dynamic columns -->
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <mubctrls:DynamicColumnsBehavior GroupColumnsByKey="False">
                        <mubctrls:DynamicColumnsBehavior.DynamicColumns>
                            <mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn 
                            Width="Auto"
                            DetailSelector="{Binding Path=Data.SuggestionsViewDynamicColumnSelector, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}">

                                <mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <!-- The DataContext for the header is represented by the TDynamicColumnKey type. In this case it is UOMLookupResult. -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UOMName}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                                <mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <!-- The DataContext for the cells is an instance that has a Root and a Detail property.
                                            The Root property refers to the TankSuggestion while the Detail property refers to an instance of TDynamicColumnCellData
                                            which in this case is TankUOMQuantity.
                                    -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Detail.DisplayQuantity}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                            </mubctrls:DynamicGridViewColumn>
                        </mubctrls:DynamicColumnsBehavior.DynamicColumns>
                    </mubctrls:DynamicColumnsBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </GridView>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>                  
</Style>
```

I also tried to alter the Binding of the DetailSelector to

```
DetailSelector={Binding Path=SuggestionsViewDynamicColumnSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

but it didn't work either.

Sorry for the long post. Feel free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `<mubctrls:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mubctrls:AutoCompleteLookup}}}"/>` to `<mubctrls:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>`

You also have to take out your Resource from Style and put it directly into your target element like so :

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy1" Data="{Binding}" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button  Content="{Binding Data.Name, Source={StaticResource Proxy1}}" Margin="45,135,26,136"/>
    </Grid>
```

This does everything correctly as expected.

Comment: doesn't work either :( I changed the Binding to '<mubctrls:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>' which give System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'BindingProxy' (HashCode=12791419); target property is 'Data' (type 'Object')

Comment: I'm not sure if i don't understand you or you didn't get my specific problem. The binding Proxy is used to inherit the DataContext to the Behavior. You need this because the Behavior is no part of the VisualTree. The Behavior is inside the style so following your example I would need to have access to {StaticResource Proxy1} inside of the Style above. Does it work for you if you change the Setter on the top to <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Data.Color, Source={StaticResource Proxy1}"/> ?

Comment: <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy1" Data="{Binding}" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="{Binding Data.Color, Source={StaticResource Proxy1}}"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
            <Button  Content="{Binding Data.Name, Source={StaticResource Proxy1}}" Margin="45,135,26,136"/>
    </Grid> This works like a charm. Try this or else, I will propose a better solution.

Comment: you are right, this simple example works. But in my case if I'm not using a style (so it works), but as soon as i change the proxy binding from the FindAncestor to just {Binding} it doesn't work anymore :( . And for your example. How would you do it, if you want to move the style in a seperate resource dictionary?

Comment: I am working on a sample app addressing your problem using behavior and styles. wait.

Comment: Clarify my doubt. Now you are showing 3 columns as in your image, and you want control over whether you can add/remove columns at runtime dependingupon your wish in your GridView control.

Comment: @StefanG I have posted new answer addressing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is two fold :

1. How to access resources embedded inside a Style element. This can be done like :

   ```
    <Style x:Key="Style1">
           <Style.Resources>
               <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor" Color="Aquamarine"/>
           </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource Style1}" x:Name="StkPnl">
           <Button Width="75" Height="25" Background="{Binding Style.Resources[MyColor], 
                          ElementName=StkPnl}"/>            
   </StackPanel>
   ```
2. And now how to bind a resource in style to BindingProxy. For example, I want to do this in resource dictionary / window.resources :

   ```
   <Style x:Key="MyStyle">
       <Style.Resources>
       <local:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush2" Color="{Binding Data.Color ,Source={StaticResource Proxy}}"/>
       </Style.Resources>
   </Style>
   ```

so that I can bind some content : `<Button Content="{Binding Data.Name}" Height="25"/>`

But I can't do this as binding is resolved before Style becomes part of our StackPanel. And Data property of BindingProxy will be null as Style is defined outside. One way to solve this issue is to keep everything under your main data display control.

Workaround if you want to keep things separate :

```
<Window ...>    
    <Window.Resources>
    <!-- Employee placeholder to allow for declarative binding. It's properties will be filled in code -->
    <local:Employee x:Key="Emp"/>

    <!-- Binding proxy to Employee / Viewmodel -->
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding (Window.Resources)[Emp], RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>

        <Style x:Key="MyStyle">
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- Here Color property is bound using BindingProxy -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush2" Color="{Binding Data.Color ,Source={StaticResource Proxy}}"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>    

        <StackPanel x:Name="Pnl1" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
            <Button Content="{Binding Data.Name, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" Background="{Binding Style.Resources[Brush2], ElementName=Pnl1}" Height="25" Width="75"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace ...
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            Employee emp = (Employee)this.Resources["Emp"];
            emp.Name = "StackOverflow";
            emp.Address = "USA";
            emp.Color = "Orange";

            //Pnl1.DataContext = emp;

        }        
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }
        public String Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @StefanG I have posted this answer in response to our discussion in earlier answer's comments.